# Optimize Custom API

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am working on Azure Mobile Service with Node.js as it's backend and I am having difficulty in handling it's timeout situation because of it's nature:

```js
var Dict = require("collections/dict");
var q = require('q');
var async = require('async');

exports.post = function(request, response) {
    console.log('body : ' + request.body);
    mssql = request.service.mssql;
    tables = request.service.tables;
    //Get payload from request body
    // extracted parameters;

    var processRecords;
    
    var sp = new Dict();
    getA(longitude, latitude)
        .then(function(results) {
            async.each(results,
                function(value, callback) {
                    var zc = value.zc;
                    var c = value.c;

                    processRecord(zc, c)
                        .then(function(record) {
                            sp.add({
                                zc: zc,
                                c: c,
                                B: record[0],
                                C: record[1],
                                D: record[2],
                                E: record[3],
                                F: record[4],
                                G: record[5]
                            }, zc);
                            
                            callback();
                        })
                        .catch(function(err) {
                            console.log("error is: " + err);
                            callback(err);
                        });
                },
                function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err);
                    } else {
                        response.send(statusCodes.OK, sp.values());
                    }
                });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err);
        });
}

function processRecord(zc,c) {
    return q.all([
         getB(zc)
        ,getC(c)
        ,getD(zc)
        ,getE(zc,c)
        ,getF(zc,c)
        ,getG(zc,c)
    ]);
}

function getA(longitude, latitude) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var sql = "a query from table function";
    mssql.query(sql, [longitude, latitude/*some param*/], {
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getB(zc) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var sql = " a queryy ";
    mssql.query(sql, [zc, /*some param*/ ], {
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getC(c) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var sql = "query";
    mssql.query(sql, [c /*some param*/], {
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getD(zc) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var sql = "query";
    mssql.query(sql, [zc /*some param*/], {
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getE(zc, c) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var sql = "query";
    mssql.query(sql, [zc,c /*some param*/], {
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getF(zc, c) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var sql = "query";
    mssql.query(sql, [zc, c /*some param*/], {
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function getG(zc, c) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var sql = "query";
    mssql.query(sql, [zc, c /*some param*/], {
        success: function(results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now it's pretty data intensive Custom API. The result I get from getA() are vary from 2-200, I want your suggestions to reduce these many data trips.

I have thought about couple of things to improve it, let me know what do you think:

1. Limit the results of getA() functions
2. Make a Table Value function in SQL Server to get all the data according to my filter I receive form client.

But each of the above have a draw back:

For example with first option I will be able to get desired results it something like I have to give client at least 10 best spots and getA() function might returns me 10 but when I filter it on these records further it doesn't have any good result.

Table Value function option might give me performance but it will not return data which I can return to user right away. Right data is well structured:

{
  zc: ...,
  c:...,
  B:[],
  ...,
  ...
}

Please give me any pointers.

Thanks,
Attiqe

P.S: All function name I gave are imaginary for the sake of posting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some brain storming I created a Table Value function that is now handling all the queries and returning me table, which I am sending it back to client. With this I reduced it from 30 sec+ response to under 5 sec.

```js
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    console.log('body : ' + request.body);
    mssql = request.service.mssql;
    tables = request.service.tables;
    //Get filters from request body
    var latitude = request.body.latitude;
    var longitude = request.body.longitude;
    
    
    getResults(longitude, latitude, offset)
        .then(function(results) {
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, results);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
            response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err);
        });
}

function getResults(longitude, latitude, offset) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM [GetResults] (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
    mssql.query(sql, [latitude, longitude /*more param*/], {
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("count: " + results.length);
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Thanks,
Attiqe